# how to display the smallest value from point to point with this array?

Tags: php

how to display the shortest distance from point to point with this array?
this is my code

```
 $nama = array( 
      "0" => array ("0" => 0, "1" => 65, "2" => 83, "3" => 73 ),
      "1" => array ("0" => 65, "1" => 0, "2" => 87, "3" => 42 ),
      "2" => array ("0" => 83, "1" => 87, "2" => 0, "3" => 21 ),
      "3" => array ("0" => 73, "1" => 42, "2" => 21, "3" => 0 )
     );
```

i have this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 65
            [2] => 83
            [3] => 73
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 65
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 87
            [3] => 42
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 83
            [1] => 87
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 21
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 73
            [1] => 42
            [2] => 21
            [3] => 0
        )

)
```

i want to display like this

From 0 To 1 = 65
From 1 To 3 = 42
From 3 To 2 = 21

or like this

Array
    (
        [A] => Array
            (
                [A] => 0
                [B] => 65
                [C] => 83
                [D] => 73
            )

```
[B] => Array
    (
        [A] => 65
        [B] => 0
        [C] => 87
        [D] => 42
    )

[C] => Array
    (
        [A] => 83
        [B] => 87
        [C] => 0
        [D] => 21
    )

[D] => Array
    (
        [A] => 73
        [B] => 42
        [C] => 21
        [D] => 0
    )
```

)

i want to display like this:
From A To B = 65
From B To D = 42
From D To C = 21

Comment: What code have you tried so far and what isn't working?

Comment: How are mysql and JS involved?

Comment: sorry, i just using php. please help me to display this array like that.

Comment: `foreach($nama as $current => $distances){ if(isset($distances[$current+1])){ echo 'From '.$current.' To '.$current+1.' = '.$distances[$current+1];}}`

Comment: The "smallest value" is always the going to be the one with the next index. You don't even need a [min](https://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)() function.

Comment: [You mean like this](https://3v4l.org/FhghM)?

Comment: kode diatas menampilkan seperti ini, From 0 To 1=65
From 1 To 2=87
From 2 To 3=21  yang saya inginkan tampilannya seperti ini  From 0 To 1 = 65
From 1 To 3 = 42
From 3 To 2 = 21

Comment: i want like this : starting from point 0, look for the smallest value. if the smallest value is at number 2, then the next line should start from array 2. if the smallest value is at number 3, then look for the smallest value of array 3

Comment: I noticed that you used a symmetric matrix. Is it just a case or your matrix is ​​always symmetrical? In this case, you could only store half matrix and decrease the number of operations. In fact From 0 To 1 = 65 is the same From 1 To 0, From 1 To 3 = 42 is the same From 3 To 1, From 3 To 2 = 21 is the same of From 2 To 3 and so on.

Comment: I think like that. but, how to display the result as I want above? Can you help me, please.